# Filter by date range in Datatable problem

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I'm implementing a date range filter in datatables, when displaying the column date in format YYYY-MM-DD , the filter works perfectly,  but I need to display the column in DD-MM-YYYY format , so i applied moment .

callback function using moment in datatable:

```
{ targets : [8], 

render : function (data, type, row) {
   return  moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
}
},
```

As a result I see the next day displayed on the columns. image below.
I would like to filter by date and the columns be ordered in the following format DD/MM/YYYY

[image: search datepicker]
clearly i'm selecting day 10 in datepicker filter and it displays day 11 on the table.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var fecha_inicio = $('#fecha_inicio').datepicker("getDate");
            // alert(fecha_inicio);
            var fecha_fin = $('#fecha_fin').datepicker("getDate");
             var arr =  data[8].split('/').reverse().join('-');
             // alert(arr);
             // var temp = arr[0] +'-'+ arr[1] +'-'+arr[2]; 

             var startDate = new Date(arr);
             startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
              // alert(startDate);


            if (fecha_inicio == null && fecha_fin == null)      { return true;}
            if (fecha_inicio == null && startDate <= fecha_fin) { return true;}
            if(fecha_fin == null && startDate >= fecha_inicio)  { return true;}
            if (startDate <= fecha_fin && startDate >= fecha_inicio) { return true;}
            return false;
        }
    );
```

[image: correct filter by date range]

If i take out the callback code the column display correctly, except the date format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to use `type` parameter，for example

```
render:function(data,type,row,meta){
    if(type=='display'){
        return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
    if(type=='filter'){
        //there is an example, show how to work, you can use whatever you want time format
        return moment(data).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    }
     if(type=='sort'){
        //maybe there is timestamp format 
        return data;
    }
    return data;
}
```

for more details check https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render  `function render( data, type, row, meta )` part of

Comment: thanks Thxopen,  i guess the problem its in the  callback function, with the format of dates, as you see above, i get both range dates from date picker, for example var fecha_inicio = $('#fecha_inicio').datepicker("getDate");  output //Mon Sep 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora de verano de Chile) , then i compare it against column Fecha var arr =  data[8].split('/').reverse().join('-');  var startDate = new Date(arr);             startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);  i think the formats are incorrect to do the comparation of dates.

Comment: so, you solve it? I suggest you use the timestamp format to compare it, maybe easier.

Comment: solved setting all dates in the format var startDate = moment(arr,'YYYY-MM-DD'); and then compared using moment,js functions isSameOrAfter, isSameOrBefore .